# How to describe user-input values in trigger - Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, triggers, oracle11g

I am learning PL/SQL and have attempted to create a trigger where once a particular condition has been met in the fact table, data will be routed to the appropriate dimension table.

There is a fact table
BHM_FACT_TABLE

Four dimension tables

- BHM_EMPLOYEES
- BHM_ACCOUNTS
- BHM_SUBSCRIBERS
- BHM_EXPENSES

In the fact table, there is an "S_Number" column that serves as the primary key for the fact table. There is also a "Code" column that lists either A, B, C, or D, depending on whether the record lists an employee, an account, a subscriber, or an expense (this is a very basic, rudimentary table, by the way).

The fact table only contains the following columns:

- S_Number
- Code
- Employees
- Accounts
- Subscribers
- Expenses.

The dimension tables contain additional columns to hold data about the employees, accounts, subscribers, and expenses (you can see the columns in details in the trigger below).

What I want the trigger to do is route the data that the user inputs to the appropriate dimension table, based on what is entered in the fact table - i.e., once a row is entered with a code of 'A', which means that this record is of an employee - then that will prompt the rest of the values input to go to the BHM_EMPLOYEES table. And so on and so forth. So, this is what I came up with:

```
CREATE OR replace TRIGGER bhm_test
  AFTER INSERT ON bhm_fact_table
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    v_code VARCHAR2 (1);
BEGIN
    SELECT code
    INTO   v_code
    FROM   bhm_fact_table;

    IF v_code = 'A' THEN
      INSERT INTO bhm_employees
                  (s_number,
                   code,
                   employeename,
                   employeeaddress,
                   employeessn,
                   employeephonenumber,
                   employeesalary)
      VALUES      ( :NEW.s_number,
                   :NEW.code,
                   employeename,
                   employeeaddress,
                   employeessn,
                   employeephonenumber,
                   employeesalary );
    ELSIF v_code = 'B' THEN
      INSERT INTO bhm_accounts
                  (s_number,
                   code,
                   accountname,
                   address,
                   taxid,
                   phonenumber,
                   invoicetotal)
      VALUES      ( :NEW.s_number,
                   :NEW.code,
                   accountname,
                   address,
                   taxid,
                   phonenumber,
                   invoicetotal );
    ELSIF v_code = 'C' THEN
      INSERT INTO bhm_subscribers
                  (s_number,
                   code,
                   subscribername,
                   subscriberaddress,
                   subscriberphone,
                   subscribertype,
                   subscriberpaid)
      VALUES      ( :NEW.s_number,
                   :NEW.code,
                   subscribername,
                   subscriberaddress,
                   subscriberphone,
                   subscribertype,
                   subscriberpaid );
    ELSIF v_code = 'D' THEN
      INSERT INTO bhm_expenses
                  (s_number,
                   code,
                   expensesname,
                   expensesamt)
      VALUES      ( :NEW.s_number,
                   :NEW.code,
                   expensesname,
                   expensesamt );
    END IF;
END;
```

For this I am getting the error 
ORA-00984: Column Not Allowed Here

for each last column listed for VALUES (employeesalary, invoicetotal, subscriberpaid, and expensesamt). I took away the bind variables for the columns that you see without them; I originally had them by all of the values, but got the "Bad Bind Variables" error.

So my first question is, what would I put in the VALUES clause, if I don't know that information yet and it won't be stored (and thus available to reference) from the fact table?

My second question is - am I even going remotely in the right direction with this trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're trying to fetch from the same table you're inserting in, so at the very least you'll run into a [Mutating table/trigger error](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mutating-table/info).

You don't need to SELECT the code, it's accessible via :NEW.CODE in your trigger.

The other problem is that you're trying to insert into the various tables without referencing the source -

```
 INSERT INTO bhm_accounts
                  (s_number,
                   code,
                   accountname,
                   address,
                   taxid,
                   phonenumber,
                   invoicetotal)
      VALUES      ( :NEW.s_number,
                   :NEW.code,
                   accountname,
                   address,
                   taxid,
                   phonenumber,
                   invoicetotal );
```

This, for instance makes no sense because you're trying to refer the same column as the source of data that you're trying to insert into.

If the columns are available in BHM_FACT_TABLE, then you can refer them using :NEW.*COLUMN_NAME* modifier and insert them into the subsequent tables.

But since you mention that these columns are not present in BHM_FACT_TABLE, and that they are user entered, then a trigger is a wrong approach to this. Triggers are useful when you have the data stored/available readily beforehand.

---

Instead of using triggers, a better way is to use a stored procedure which will insert the data into the various tables based on the columns.

Comment: The only columns in the fact table are S_Number and Code. The other columns are not available in the fact table, only in the dimension tables.

Comment: What's the source of the data for the other columns then?

Comment: Somehow, directly from the user's input. Though I am not sure if that is possible, and I am definitely sure that I don't know how that would be implemented.

Comment: if it's user input then it must be available in some table for the trigger to work. Alternatively, skip the trigger altogether and use a stored procedure that will check the code and populate to other tables when the user submits the data